# How to use sqlcmd to create a database

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I have a .sql script and I want to build a database from it. How to do it in sqlcmd? I know it's like:

```
CREATE DATABASE dbName
GO
```

But how to specify the .sql script and location to build the database?

Comment: This is off-topic. You are asking how to use `sqlcmd`, not a programming question.

Comment: @Oded Questions about 'software tools commonly used by programmers' are on topic

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use [@Jeremiah Peschka's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8693578/297408) to supply the `sqlcmd` utility with the script to execute.

As for the location for the newly created database, it can be specified as part of the [`CREATE DATABASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176061.aspx) command:

```
CREATE DATABASE dbName
ON (
  NAME = dbName_dat,
  FILENAME = 'D:\path\to\dbName.mdf'
)
LOG ON (
  NAME = dbName_log,
  FILENAME = 'D:\path\to\dbName.ldf'
)
```

As you can see from the linked article, you can specify other properties as well, like initial size, maximum size etc.

Comment: Hey @AER, thank you for [your contribution](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19480583). I've decided to reject it as irrelevant because the question was clearly about running a script stored in a file rather than typing and executing the command(s) in a terminal session. When a script is meant to be run as a single batch, ending it with a `GO` is optional (perhaps you already know that).

Answer (score 17):

This is very simple. Just enter following command to run sqlcmd: 
`sqlcmd -U sa -P password`
Then enter:

```
CREATE DATABASE MYDB
GO
```

This will create the db. Then enter "quit" to exit.

Answer (score 13):

without a file:

```
sqlcmd -Q "CREATE DATABASE HelloWorld"
```

Answer (score 11):

```
sqlcmd -i C:\path\to\file.sql
```

More options can be found in [SQL Server books online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

use this:
sqlcmd -i "c:\my scripts\my script.sql"

see [sqlcmd description at MS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) for other options