# How to run an SQL script in a batch file

Tags: sql, sql-server, batch-file

I have a a SQL script that creates a database, and want to know how to run this from a batch file at a command prompt.
Do I create a batch file with a few lines of code pointing to the location of the `.sql` file, or create a new batch file containing the contents of the `.sql` file?

Comment: osql.exe is one option you can explore.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a batch file and use the -i flag with sqlcmd.exe, where -i sets the path to the .sql file you want to run:

```
sqlcmd.exe -i F:\wherever\the\file\is
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx for a full list of the flags and this post, [How to use sqlcmd to create a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8693561/how-to-use-sqlcmd-to-create-a-database).

Answer (score 0):

is quite easy, you only need 3 things:

SQL Client Path/
Script Path/
SQL Conection data/

Then you can run it directly from the batch without any complex script - let me know if you have the info I can arrange it.

regards