# HOW to create SQL Server 2017 database scripts using sqlcmd

Tags: sql-server, database-migration

I have a database schema sitting in SQL Server 2017 running on Ubuntu. I have a separate SQL Server 2008 R2. I need the database structure to migrate from 2017 -> 2008 R2 server and cannot find the right direction to start with. I had created the backup and tried to restore but it seems we cannot restore in that fashion. I think "create scripts" will do the job but I do not have management studio. All I have is `sqlcmd` running on the instance with 2017 version. So can I run "create scripts" to get the structure of the database and store in a single `.sql` file.?

Comment: In a word, no. `sqlcmd` can run scripts, but it can't create them. For Linux, you want [`mssql-scripter`](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-scripter) (disclaimer: no personal experience).

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks. I was able to create the scripts using mssql-scripter. I had to make some changes in the scripts but was very much helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer: [How to use sqlcmd to create a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8693561/how-to-use-sqlcmd-to-create-a-database)

Here you go:

```
 sqlcmd -i C:\path\to\file.sql
```

More options can be found in  [SQL Server books online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: Thanks but I really need the other way round. I need the schema scripts to be generated which I can use in other lower version database to create the exact same schema. If that makes any sense to you.